# Prove $\sin (-\alpha ) = -\sin(\alpha)$ and $\cos(-\alpha) = \cos(\alpha)$

Tags: trigonometry

I want to demonstrate these basic trigonometric identities but I have no idea how to do it

$\sin (-\alpha ) = -\sin(\alpha)$

$\cos(-\alpha) = \cos(\alpha)$

help me please

thank you

Comment: Which postulates have you assumed true?

Comment: Hello Mostafa Ayaz, I do not have assumed postulates

Comment: What is your definition of $\sin(\alpha)$?

Comment: Hi @J.W.Tanner

Right-angled triangle definition
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Right-angled_triangle_definition

Comment: @Jose: if you have no definition/postulate about the trigonometric functions, there is nothing you can prove. And if you say "the well-known" sine and cosine, then it is also "well-known" that they are odd and even functions.

Comment: @Jose: please be explicit. Chances are high that this will just tell you the answer. A non-explicit answer is "by symmetry".

Comment: @Jose:  what is your definition of sin$(-\alpha)$?

Comment: @YvesDaoust ok
I don't know the unit circle definition, is what I was looking for
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little hint: look at the unit circle (draw it) and look at the definition of sin and cos for a given point

Comment: I will do it ElMiho

Comment: This certainly helps one to appreciate that the identities should hold, if @Jose knows the relationship between sin, cos and angles in the circle. However, whether they will be able to produce a geometric proof depends on what definitions of sin, cos they are using!

Comment: You're right @MorganRogers - the unit circle def of cos/sin is clearly what I had in mind and, if they use that definition, probably the easier one to use for this problem

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Taylor expansions for sin($\alpha$) and cos($\alpha$).

$sin(\alpha)=\alpha-\alpha^3/3!+\alpha^5/5!+...$

$cos(\alpha)=1-\alpha^2/2!+\alpha^4/4!+...$

So,

$sin(-\alpha)=-\alpha+\alpha^3/3!-\alpha^5/5!+... =(-1)(\alpha-\alpha^3/3!+\alpha^5/5!+...)=-sin(\alpha)$

$cos(-\alpha)=1-(-\alpha)^2/2!+(-\alpha)^4/4!+...=1-\alpha^2/2!+\alpha^4/4!+...=cos(\alpha)$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Consider the right angled triangles, $\triangle OPA$ and $\triangle OPA'$,

$$\sin \alpha = \frac{PA}{OA} = \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
$$\cos \alpha = \frac{OP}{OA} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
$$\sin(-\alpha) = \frac{PA'}{OA'} = \frac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = -\sin \alpha$$
$$\cos(-\alpha) = \frac{OP}{OA'} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \cos \alpha$$

You can also prove this by expanding taylor series of $\sin \alpha$ and $\cos \alpha$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos(-\alpha)+i\sin(-\alpha)=e^{-i\alpha}=\frac1{e^{i\alpha}}=\frac1{\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha}=\frac{\cos\alpha-i\sin\alpha}{\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha}=\cos\alpha-i\sin\alpha.$$

By equating the real and imaginary parts,

$$\cos(-\alpha)=\cos\alpha,\\\sin(-\alpha)=-\sin\alpha.$$